# Unary + operator in JavaScript applied to ' ' (string with space)

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, boolean, unary-operator

I am confused by the following code:

```
Boolean(' '); // true
Boolean(''); // false
+' '; // 0
+''; // 0
```

My assumptions:

1. Since `Boolean(' ')` evaluates to `true`, `' '` is a truthy value.
2. Since `Boolean('')` evaluates to `false`, `''` is a falsy value.
3. Since the unary `+` operator attempts to convert its operand into a number, it should convert a falsy value to 0, and a truthy value to 1.

Question:
Why does the unary `+` operator convert a truthy value (i.e. `' '`) to 0?

Please feel free to point out everything that is wrong about my assumptions, and anything that I am missing. Thank you so much!

=================

EDIT AFTER INITIAL THREE REPLIES

Thank you guys, you are great, and your are right! Here's what I found in the ES6 specs:

> "The conversion of a String to a Number value (...:)
> This value is determined in two steps: first, a mathematical
> value (MV) is derived from the String numeric literal; second, this
> mathematical value is rounded as described below. The MV on any
> grammar symbol, not provided below, is the MV for that symbol defined
> in 11.8.3.1.
>
> The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0.
>
> The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: StrWhiteSpace is 0.
>
> The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: StrWhiteSpaceopt StrNumericLiteral
> StrWhiteSpaceopt is the MV of StrNumericLiteral, no matter whether
> white space is present or not."

(Source: https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-mv-s)

So that would explain why both `+''` and `+' '` evaluate to 0.

I was also confused why `Boolean()` did not evaluate both to `false`:

> The abstract operation ToBoolean converts argument to a value of type Boolean according to Table 10:
> (...)
> String: Return false if argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise return true.

Source: https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-toboolean

So that's why `Boolean(''); // false` and `Boolean(' '); // true`.

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: I would assume the string is having the whitespace trimmed, since `+'    1     '` returns `1`

Comment: This might be wrong since I'm no docs hero, but https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-stringnumericvalue is one of the internals used by the unary operator ( if you follow the trail through these docs) And the implementation of StringNumericValue specifies we return positive zero when we have a string of whitespace.

Comment: @Shilly: Thanks for pointing me to the docs - I'm no docs hero either and this is the first time I looked at the ES6 specs. I did so research and added what I found to my question. Thank you!

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised that the duplicate answer also references the StringNumericValue specification, so all credit kinda goes to Felix for figuring this out in 2012.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Thank you, I didn't think of this. You're right. When converting a string to a number: 
"The MV [mathematical value] of StringNumericLiteral ::: StrWhiteSpaceopt StrNumericLiteral StrWhiteSpaceopt is the MV of StrNumericLiteral, no matter whether white space is present or not." URL: https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-mv-s Thank you!